# Light switch auto turns off but not on

Tags: switch

I have a Leviton light switch (picture). It automatically turns off after about 15 mins of absence of motion and will turn on if I enter the room only a few minutes after it has turned off.

However, if a long enough period elapses it won't automatically turn on and I have to press the button again.

Is there a setting to change so it automatically turns on by itself at any time?

Update: on the inner metal plate it says: "Cat. No. IPV15"

[image: Leviton light switch]

Comment: What model is your occupancy sensor? We'll need a model number in order to figure out where the right setting is

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the model. That looks like an IPS05 or and IPV05. The IPV05 is manual on only, the IPS05 will act as manual on if the ambient light level dial behind the face of the device is set to 0.

There are also models that instead of dials have a row of tiny slide switches called dip switches that control the vacancy/occupancy operation and the on/off time delay.

The sensitivity dials or dip switches are usually located behind the pushbutton.  If it is an IPV05/IPS05 to access the controls first you need to remove the trim cover, then gently push down and pull forward on the tiny tabs that on the top of the plastic that hold the button assembly to the switch.